# Letting user to set up his own homepage doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest

Basically, I have 2 forms. Home is a form which is created when the menu item in the main form is clicked. The menu item pops up this form, which asks user to put a desired URL as his/her homepage. Also contains "Ok" and "Cancel" buttons. The url should be saved in a string, so that I can access it from Form1 when pressing the homepage button. The homepage button should load the url that was saved into the richTextBox. I got an error saying that my URI is not valid when call `httpwebrequest.create(string URLSavedInHomepage)`

```
public partial class Home:Form
{
    //string homeURL = "";
    string homepage;
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentInput = url.Text;
        homepage = "http://" + currentInput;
        setHomepage(homepage);
        this.Close();
    }


    private void CancelB_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public string getHomepage()
    {
        return homepage;
    }
    public void setHomepage(string home)
    {
        homepage = home;
    }

    private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentInput = url.Text;
        homepage = "http://" + currentInput;
        setHomepage(homepage);
    }
```

some code from the Main Form:

```
private void HomePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Home home = new Home();
        URLInput.Text = home.getHomepage();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLInput.Text);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

    }
private void ChangeHomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
//this is menu item to call 
    {
        Home h = new Home();
        h.Show();
    }
```

Note, I **can't** use WebBrowser class as requirements say I can't use it, otherwise I'd just use `.Navigate()`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, @John. Will keep in mind for future.

Comment: that's the value of `URLInput.Text` when you get the error?

Comment: hey @Jonesy, yep. When I try to run the code, it says "Invalid URI; URI is empty".

Comment: sorry, typo.  I meant, **what's** the value of `URLInput.Text`

Comment: @Jonesy, the value is the URL typed in by a user. If it was "www.facebook.com" then it should be http:// www. facebook.com (sorry, it automatically makes it a link if I don't put spaces between characters) for URLInput.Text. Seems like it doesn't save the url at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as follows (I assume that URLInput is a control on the main form):

```
private void HomePage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URLInput.Text);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

private void ChangeHomeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
//this is menu item to call 
{
    using(Home h = new Home())
    {
        h.ShowDialog();
        var homePageUrl = h.getHomePage();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(homePageUrl))
            return;
        URLInput.Text = homePageUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't ShowDialog() pops up a Home form itself? I don't really need a form to pop up when I click the homepage button. I just need the saved URL to be shown in the URLInput, so I can press enter or click the "GO!" button to load the actual page.

Comment: The Problem is that you create separate instances of the Home form in the two menu Event handlers. If you Change the second handler to Show a Dialog and store the result in a field in the parent form, then you can use the value of this field in the first handler. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Markus. Fixed now. Got your idea, checked it and added some code to activate the homepage button. 

Will probably play around with files as well to make it more efficient. I suppose if I close my application and open it again it will not remember the homepageUrl value, isn't it?

Comment: Nevermind, sorted. Wrote the url to a file, so that it can be loaded when app is launched again. Thanks a lot :)